# Accepting invalid SSL certificates using WinRT

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro, security, windows-runtime

There are scenarios where you want your application to accept invalid SSL certificates (testing environment/ self signed certificates etc).

In the .NET world one would use the `ServerCertificateValidationCallback` class to do so. Unfortunately the class doesn't exist in a WinRT context.

I need to consume a Web API using WinRT which is hosted on a server without a valid ssl certificate.

How do you accept invalid ssl certificates in WinRT using the `HttpClient` class or any other appropriate class.

Any help or alternatives would much appreciated.

Comment: Alternatively, you could add your self signed testing certificates to your local certificate store so they would be seen as valid.

Comment: I was thinking about that one as well and theoretically this should work, but: The device I am using is a peace of hardware you can buy and it's just to complicatedt to explain normal users how to ssh into a machine, grap te certificate and so on and so on. Or would there be a way to automate this?

Comment: Depends on the operating system.  You could supply the certificate in a variety of formats along with installation instructions for different operating systems (most of them, it will be basically "download this and double click it").  If you're working with a company, you could put a request through to their IT dept and they can probably do the installation on their employees' machines

Comment: @Wug - The only operating system we could be talking about is a preview version Windows 8.  Windows RT and Windows 8 devices are not yet in the wild.  Although the process to accept what technical is an invalid ssl certificate will be the same for Windows RT and Windows 8.

Comment: @Ramhound I think you may not understand the issue here. The question is how to accept an invalid certificate via code on the WinRT platform. You down vote is a bit weired though. Sorry

Comment: That would make sense I guess. Does WinRT provide a way to access the OS' certificate store? A quick google search yields nothing.  I'm not sure if the installation would work the same way for win8 as it does with earlier versions, but for win7 it's just a double click deal.  There's probably a way to automate it *(but I'm not sure what it is.)

Comment: The question's just as valid for an unreleased OS. +1!

Comment: Perhaps you can simply use BouncyCastle

Comment: @Wug Adding a cert to the global cert store just because one application wants to use a different certificate policy looks like a bad idea to me. Global solution to a local problem.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: The security of either approach is arguable.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

in silverlight, it wasn't allowed. I haven't seen anything that says it's allowed in winrt.

Comment: this indicates you can't do it: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/4a776e8c-0e10-4f03-908f-7f765d914080  -- just another case in which MS says no and apple says "Yeah sure- we love developers!"

Comment: I think for now I have no other choice but accept your answer. Lets hope they change something about this in the future!

Comment: Yeah- looks like they added it for win8 and 10, nice.

Answer (score 4):

The following code worked for me for the debugging scenario:

```
var filter = new HttpBaseProtocolFilter();
#if DEBUG
    filter.IgnorableServerCertificateErrors.Add(ChainValidationResult.Expired);
    filter.IgnorableServerCertificateErrors.Add(ChainValidationResult.Untrusted);
    filter.IgnorableServerCertificateErrors.Add(ChainValidationResult.InvalidName);
#endif
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient(filter)) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining how to do this with Webview?

Comment: No idea for a solution with webview. The original question is not about webview.

Why this question is not useful?

Comment: Thanks Dschüsä, that helped a lot for my Windows 10 app!

Comment: When I used 'filter', I get an error - "cannot convert from 'Windows.Web.Http.Filters.HttpBaseProtocolFilter' to 'System.Net.Http.HttpMessageHandler"

Comment: You're using HttpClient from System.Net.Http namespace instead of Windows.Web.Http Namespace.